# Cannot Retry a Request Which Hasn't Previously Been Completed

Tags: wildfly

I had to copy some existing beans and their remote interfaces within an existing working application. Now whenever I call one of the methods, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000032: Cannot retry a request which hasn't previously been completed
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.retryRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:203)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.sendRequestWithPossibleRetries(EJBInvocationHandler.java:256)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.sendRequestWithPossibleRetries(EJBInvocationHandler.java:265)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:198)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:181)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:144)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.createRawSTRProfiles(Unknown Source)
at org.acme.project.CreateSomethingRunnable.run(CreateSomethingRunnable.java:76)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

The same bean works for other method calls. There is no other exception on neither client nor server side, a breakpoint inside the server method in question is never called. I have no idea how to debug, and Google is oblivous to this error message. We are using WildFly 8.1.0.Final.

Can anybody help shed light on this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Y'know, it's just about *got* to be a subtle error in *your* code ... the stuff that's trying to issue "this" method-call.  The meaning of the message itself appears to be clear:  if the request hasn't completed, you can't "retry" it.  Well, did this particular call, say, *fail?*  Maybe there's a tpyo in it.  Something not-quite-right about *this particular* one.  Grab a nearby colleague and have them take a look at it with you.  Could well be a *"d'oh!"* problem . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root exception for us was a `ClassNotFoundError` because an entirely unrelated JAR inside the EAR had the wrong version number.

Double-check everything. We dismantled the value that was sent (setting all fields to null). When that worked, we set the fields to objects again one by one, checking the classes in question for `Serializable` (because sometimes a missing `Serializable` causes similar exceptions).

In short, ensure that all classes going over the wire implement the Serializable interface.